# Select values method advice

Tags: php, select

I am not sure how should I do the following thing. I have several values (for example)
`$value1 = 2; $value2 = 3; $value4 = 0;` and I need to pick up just those that are bigger than 0. So could you say with what maethod it is possible to do? I was thinking about array but I dont know how to check after each value wether it is or not bigger than 0. The list of values is little bit bigger and I dont want to write for each value `if ($value1 > 0){ ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put values in an array and use array_filter. This works -

```
<?php
    $value1 = 11;
    $value2 = 123;
    $value3 = 0;
    $value4 = 34;
    $value5 = 0;
    $arr = array_filter(array($value1, $value2, $value3, $value4, $value5) , function($v){return $v > 0;});
    var_dump($arr);
    /*
        OUTPUT:
        array
          0 => int 11
          1 => int 123
          3 => int 34
    */
?>
```

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function for you.. you can call it like biggerthanzero($value1,$value2, ... etc)

```
function biggerthanzero()
{
   // if no arguments are given, return an empty array
if (func_num_args() == 0) {
    return array();
}
$results = array();
// func_get_args() returns the parameters you passed as an array
foreach (func_get_args() as $arg){
    if ($arg > 0){
        $results[] = $arg;
    }
}
return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First - i think you should use one array instead of many separate variables.

...but if your variables are named "$valueX" where X changes from 1 to 9 you can iterate all of them with something like this:

```
for($i=1; $i<10; $i++) {
    $variable_name= "value".$i;
    if ( $$variable_name > 0 ) { ... }
}
```